# Invariance of Functional Integration Measure

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Let us consider the functional integral:
\begin{equation}
\int \mathcal{D} A e^{iS[A]}
\end{equation}
where $S[A]$ is the action for $U(1)$ gauge field and 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}A\equiv \mathcal{D}A_0 \mathcal{D}A_1 \mathcal{D}A_2 \mathcal{D}A_3; \\
\mathcal{D}A_i = \prod_x dA_i(x).
\end{equation}

Now I have two questions:

**1. How to show that the integration measure $\mathcal{D} A $ is invariant under the gauge transformation:**
\begin{equation}
A_\mu (x) \to A_\mu (x) + \frac{1}{e}\partial_\mu \alpha(x)
\end{equation}
**2. How to show that the integration measure $\mathcal{D} A $ is invariant under the Lorentz transformation?**

Comment: **Hints:** **1.** $\alpha(x)$ is a set function, it isn't being varied over like $A_\mu(x)$ is. **2.** How does a measure change under a change of coordinates in regular integration?

Comment: Doesn't the answer to this depend on the regulator?  In particular, couldn't one concoct some terrible regulator that would render the integration measure non-gauge-invariant?

Comment: @joshphysics: You can certainly break symmetries with a non-covariant regulator, but it is almost universally assumed that one is using a gauge-covariant regulator since the consequence of gauge non-covariance are so dire.

Comment: @Will: Can u elaborate the hint for question no. **2** ?

Comment: Lorentz transformations take $A_\mu \rightarrow A^\prime_{\nu} = \Lambda_{\nu}^{\mu}A_{\mu}$, right? Now, consider the process you go through when changing coordinates in regular integration of several variables. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: @Will: In that case the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation, det$(\Lambda^\mu_\nu)$ will be $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 4):

In quantum field theory, when manipulating the path integral, we naively assume the measures (or strictly speaking the product of the measures and integrand) are invariant under the gauge transformations. In a fundamental paper, Fujikawa demonstrated the flaw in this assumption (in certain cases), and how to rigorously compute the analogue of a Jacobian factor for the path integral, which he employed to derive the chiral anomaly of quantum electrodynamics. For a complete derivation, I recommend the sources:

- *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*, by Peskin and Schroeder, Chapter 19, pg. 651+
- Beyond the Standard Model, Lecture 5 (13/14, Course by Prof. R. Mann), Perimeter Institute

I hope these may provide some clarification regarding the change of the path integral measure under a general transformation of the constituent fields.